# JSON missing outside square brackets

Tags: php, json

I need to have JSON objects inside an array like:

```
[{"term":"hemisected","description":"Cut into two equal parts; to bisect, especially along a medial longitudinal plane."},{"term":"polyuria","description":"A condition usually defined as excessive or abnormally large production or passage of urine."},{"term":"dyspnoea","description":"Shortness of breath."}]
```

However the following is outputting JSON as separate objects:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
        $data = array(
        'term' => $row['term'],
        'description' => $row['definition']
        );
echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Like:

```
{"term":"hemisected","description":"Cut into two equal parts; to bisect, especially along a medial longitudinal plane."}{"term":"polyuria","description":"A condition usually defined as excessive or abnormally large production or passage of urine."}{"term":"dyspnoea","description":"Shortness of breath."}
```

Comment: put `$data[] = array(...` and your `json_encode()` must be in the end/outside of that loop

Comment: @kevinabelita...thanks, put this into an answer

Comment: I typically also add the two flags to remove the '/' escaping and to preserve non-ASCII characters, provided everything downstream understands Unicode. When outputting for debugging, I also use the pretty-print flag to format the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the json structure is not well build because of the fact that it is called during the loop. It must be called after the array (in this case `$data`) has been built. Consider this example:

```
$data = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
    $data[] = array(
        'term' => $row['term'],
        'description' => $row['definition'],
    );
}

echo json_encode($data);
```